# Why does rgeo have CAPI and FFI factories to achieve the same goal?

Tags: ruby, rgeo

If I understand the [Rgeo](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo) doc & code correctly, there's `CAPIFactory` which is supposed to link to GEOS and there is `FFIFactory` using `ffi-geos` gem which links to GEOS using FFI.

Both of these seem to be achieving the same objective.
Why does Rgeo implement 2 separate factories for the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

The `CAPIFactory` can be used for versions of Ruby that support C Extensions. The most common version of Ruby (MRI) is written in C and thus supports C Extensions, but other kinds (JRuby for example) are written in Java or other languages that don't support C Extensions. In that case, they can use the `FFIFactory` to interface with GEOS, but it is not as fast as the native `CAPIFactory`.

Basically, the `FFIFactory` gives the ability to use GEOS to all versions of Ruby at the cost of some performance.